# 困りました or 困っています

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'm reading a graded reader about the 地蔵（じぞう）folktale.  The おじいさん gets to the statues and finds them with snow on their heads and bodies.  He removes the snow from them and places hats on five out of six of them.  Then he says: あれ、困りましたねえ.  After that, he realizes there's one left without a hat, he takes his off and places it on it's head.  My question is, when he says 困りました, does he mean he was troubled before he put the hats on the five statues, and after that he wasn't?  Or that he's troubled because there's one without a hat left?  I think it's the former, and if it were the latter, it would be 困っています.  Is that assumption correct?

Comment: In fact た is not just a tense marker here. https://hermes-ir.lib.hit-u.ac.jp/rs/bitstream/10086/19300/1/kokusai0000200130.pdf

Comment: 困りました is better learned as an idiom that is said when you feel you're in trouble. The た is used to express the _speaker's_ emotion. 困っています would be more objective and used to describe the _subject's_ state. You may also see 困ります; this is used to express the _speaker's_ emotion, too, but used a bit differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like he said it after he realized there's one without a hat. In daily speech people say 困った to themselves or about someone else at the moment they realize something's wrong. Saying 困っています sounds like you're asking for some kind of long term help.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, when he says 困りました, does he mean he was troubled before he put the hats on the five statues, and after that he wasn't? Or that he's troubled because there's one without a hat left? I think it's the former, and if it were the latter, it would be 困っています. Is that assumption correct?

Think of 困りましたねえ、or こまったねぇ, is an idiom and you are better off not dissecting it. Simlpy think of the phrase as

"Oh no. This won't do."

おじいさん simply encountered a six-statue-and-five-hat situation, laments it, and then finds a solution. No more, no less going on. It's an idiom. It's sort of like how you are better off not dissecting "You are welcome." and wonder what is being welcomed and such.